# asp.net - Fill Data List with Entity Data Source Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

How to fill **Data List** with **Entity Data Source Control** or **Code** with **Stored Procedure**, Can not find any solution.

Comment: please consider sharing some code..

Comment: @user7417866 I have no code yet I need to know how to even start

Comment: Check my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you are looking for...

I've created simple DataList in asp.net which populate user data using EntityFramework..

I assume you have stored procedure / Entities created into your code..

On ASPX page design ..

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <table class = "table">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">
                    <b><%# Eval("UserName") %></b>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    IsAdmin:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("IsAdmin")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ID:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("UserId")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
    <asp:Button ID="LoadFromEntity" runat="server" Text="Load From Entites" OnClick="LoadFromEntity_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="LoatFromStoredProcedure" runat="server" Text="Load From Strored Procedure" OnClick="LoatFromStoredProcedure_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

and on backend C# you need to bind this list to data source..

```
protected void LoadFromEntity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (UserEntites ObjUserEntities = new UserEntites())
            {
                DataList1.DataSource = ObjUserEntities.UserMasters.ToList();
                DataList1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void LoatFromStoredProcedure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (UserEntites ObjUserEntities = new UserEntites())
            {
                List<USP_FetchUserDetails_Result> OBjUserDetails = new List<USP_FetchUserDetails_Result>();
                OBjUserDetails = ObjUserEntities.USP_FetchUserDetails().ToList();
                DataList1.DataSource = OBjUserDetails;
                DataList1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

I've kept button name as per stored procedure / Entity name, this covers your both scenarios..

Hope this helps :)

This is how output looks like..

[image]